# Why does not beamer cover math contents in `align` when setting covered content to `transparent`?

Tags: beamer, align, transparency

When using `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` the math contents in align are invisible and shown only as specified in the overlay specifications. However, when using `\setbeamercovered{transparent=<percentage>}`, `beamer` will show all `align` contents that are supposed to be covered.

In the MWE, all the contents adjacent to the transparent one should also stay transparent, but it is not clear for me why this is not the case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=1cm, sidebar width right=1cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5mm, text margin right=0.5mm}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{block}

        \begin{align*}
            A \uncover<+->{&= B \\}
            \uncover<+->{A &= C \\}
            \uncover<+->{A &= D \\}
            \uncover<+->{A &= E \\}
        \end{align*}

        \begin{equation*}
            A = B \uncover<+->{= C} \uncover<+->{= D} \uncover<+->{= E}
        \end{equation*}

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[Log file for the run](https://pastebin.com/jvECXQ0s)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on my TeXLive 2018 distribution when I compile the code with pdfplatex and view the pdf with either acroread or preview. What compiler and viewer are you using?

Comment: I use MiKTeX with XeLaTeX. Here is a link of the MWE in Overleaf 

https://www.overleaf.com/7395593956fytspkbhhqnm

It does not seem that the issue is reproduced with Overleaf either. It seems that it is about TeXStudio or MiKTeX

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Texstudio is just an editor and unrelated to the problem. Which version of beamer do you have? You find this information in the .log file. With v3.55 I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: The log file says the following about beamer version: 

Document Class: beamer 2018/12/02 v3.55

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Can you add the complete .log file?

Comment: @samcarter I just added it in the main topic

Comment: I would try excluding the = from the uncover: `\uncover<+->{A} &\uncover<.->{= C} \\ ` but I can not test this because I can not reproduce the issue on my system (pdfTeX version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.2.24), beamer 2018/12/02 v3.55).

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Thanks for the log file. This seems to be a problem with xelatex. Can you change to pdflatex or do you need xelatex for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to some problem with xelatex. For a workaround you can use `\onslide`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=1cm, sidebar width right=1cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5mm, text margin right=0.5mm}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{block}

        \begin{align*}
            A \onslide<+->{&= B \\}
            \onslide<+->{A &= C \\}
            \onslide<+->{A &= D \\}
            \onslide<+->{A &= E \\}
        \end{align*}

        \begin{equation*}
            A = B \uncover<+->{= C} \uncover<+->{= D} \uncover<+->{= E}
        \end{equation*}

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]